# Why Java Optional performance increase with number of chained calls?

Tags: java, performance, option-type

I was recently asked about the performance of java 8 Optional. After some searching, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696884/performance-of-java-optional) and several blog posts, with contradicting answers. So I benchmarked it using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) and I don't understand my findings.

Here is the gist of my benchmark code ([full code](https://github.com/EtienneMiret/java8-benchmark) is available on GitHub):

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class OptionalBenchmark {

  private Room room;

  @Param({ "empty", "small", "large", "full" })
  private String filling;

  @Setup
  public void setUp () {
    switch (filling) {
      case "empty":
        room = null;
        break;
      case "small":
        room = new Room(new Flat(new Floor(null)));
        break;
      case "large":
        room = new Room(new Flat(new Floor(new Building(new Block(new District(null))))));
        break;
      case "full":
        room = new Room(new Flat(new Floor(new Building(new Block(new District(new City(new Country("France"))))))));
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported filling.");
    }
  }

  @Benchmark
  public String nullChecks () {
    if (room == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Flat flat = room.getFlat();
    if (flat == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Floor floor = flat.getFloor();
    if (floor == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Building building = floor.getBuilding();
    if (building == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Block block = building.getBlock();
    if (block == null) {
      return null;
    }

    District district = block.getDistrict();
    if (district == null) {
      return null;
    }

    City city = district.getCity();
    if (city == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Country country = city.getCountry();
    if (country == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return country.getName();
  }

  @Benchmark
  public String optionalsWithMethodRefs () {
    return Optional.ofNullable (room)
        .map (Room::getFlat)
        .map (Flat::getFloor)
        .map (Floor::getBuilding)
        .map (Building::getBlock)
        .map (Block::getDistrict)
        .map (District::getCity)
        .map (City::getCountry)
        .map (Country::getName)
        .orElse (null);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public String optionalsWithLambdas () {
    return Optional.ofNullable (room)
        .map (room -> room.getFlat ())
        .map (flat -> flat.getFloor ())
        .map (floor -> floor.getBuilding ())
        .map (building -> building.getBlock ())
        .map (block -> block.getDistrict ())
        .map (district -> district.getCity ())
        .map (city -> city.getCountry ())
        .map (country -> country.getName ())
        .orElse (null);
  }

}
```

And the results I got were:

```
Benchmark                                  (filling)   Mode  Cnt           Score         Error  Units
OptionalBenchmark.nullChecks                   empty  thrpt  200   468835378.093 ±  895576.864  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.nullChecks                   small  thrpt  200   306602013.907 ±  136966.520  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.nullChecks                   large  thrpt  200   259996142.619 ±  307584.215  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.nullChecks                    full  thrpt  200   275954974.981 ± 4154597.959  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithLambdas         empty  thrpt  200   460491457.335 ±  322920.650  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithLambdas         small  thrpt  200    98604468.453 ±   68320.074  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithLambdas         large  thrpt  200    67648427.470 ±  206810.285  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithLambdas          full  thrpt  200   167124820.392 ± 1229924.561  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs      empty  thrpt  200   460690135.554 ±  273853.568  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs      small  thrpt  200    98639064.680 ±   56848.805  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs      large  thrpt  200    68138436.113 ±  158409.539  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs       full  thrpt  200   169603006.971 ±   52646.423  ops/s
```

First of all, when given a null reference, Optional and null checks behave pretty much the same. I guess this is because there is only one instance of `Optional.empty ()`, so any `.map ()` method call on it just returns itself.

When the given object is non-null and contains a chain of non-null attributes, however, a new Optional has to be instantiated on each call to `.map ()`. Hence, performance degrade much more quickly than with null checks. Makes sense. Expect for my `full` filling, where the performance all of a sudden increase. So what is the magic going on here? Am I doing something wrong in my benchmark?

## Edit

The parameters from my first run were the default from JMH: each benchmark was ran in 10 different forks, with 20 warmup iterations of 1s each, and then 20 measurement iterations of 1s each. I believe those value are sane, since I trust the libraries I use. However, since I was told I wasn’t warming up enough, here is the result of a longer test (200 warmup iterations and 200 measurement iteration for each of the 10 forks):

```
# JMH version: 1.19
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_152, VM 25.152-b16
# VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 200 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 200 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time

# Run complete. Total time: 17:49:25

Benchmark                                  (filling)   Mode   Cnt           Score         Error  Units
OptionalBenchmark.nullChecks                   empty  thrpt  2000   471803721.972 ±  116120.114  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.nullChecks                   small  thrpt  2000   289181482.246 ± 3967502.916  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.nullChecks                   large  thrpt  2000   260222478.406 ±  105074.121  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.nullChecks                    full  thrpt  2000   282487728.710 ±   71214.637  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithLambdas         empty  thrpt  2000   460931830.242 ±  335263.946  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithLambdas         small  thrpt  2000    98688943.879 ±   20485.863  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithLambdas         large  thrpt  2000    67262330.106 ±   50465.262  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithLambdas          full  thrpt  2000   168070919.770 ±  352435.666  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs      empty  thrpt  2000   460998599.579 ±   85063.337  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs      small  thrpt  2000    98707338.408 ±   17231.648  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs      large  thrpt  2000    68052673.021 ±   55285.427  ops/s
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs       full  thrpt  2000   169259067.479 ±  174402.212  ops/s
```

As you can see, we have almost the same figures.

Comment: I think you're not warming up the JVM enough, and a 200 Count is too low. See: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/5221149). `full` is likely faster because JIT finally kicked in (see Rule 2 to check if that's the case).

Comment: Nice post! Have you tried to turn off the JIT with something like [`-XX:CompileThreshold=10000000000000`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)?

Comment: I’ll try do another run with the JIT disabled this night (European time). We'll see.

Comment: Your benchmark looks correct, don't listen to comments :) JMH defaults are sane. It already cares about warm-up. There is no need to run the test *so* long. And don't event try `-XX:CompileThreshold` - it [does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614237/3448419) in modern JDK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even such a powerful tool like JMH is not able to save from all benchmarking pitfalls.
I've found two different issues with this benchmark.

#### 1.

HotSpot JIT compiler speculatively optimizes code basing on runtime profile. In the given "full" scenario `Optional` never sees `null` values. That's why `Optional.ofNullable` method (also called by `Optional.map`) happens to be optimized exclusively for non-null path which constructs a new non-empty `Optional`. In this case JIT is able to eliminate all short-lived allocations and perform all `map` operations without intermediate objects.

```
public static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(T value) {
    return value == null ? empty() : of(value);
}
```

In "small" and "large" scenarios the mapping sequence finally ends with `Optional.empty()`. That is, both branches of `ofNullable` method are compiled, and JIT is no longer able to eliminate allocations of intermediate `Optional` objects - data flow graph appears to be too complex for Escape Analysis to succeed.

Check it by running JMH with `-prof gc`, and you'll see that "small" allocates 48 bytes (3 Optionals) per iteration, "large" allocates 96 bytes (6 Optionals), and "full" allocates nothing.

```
Benchmark                                                      (filling)  Mode  Cnt     Score     Error   Units
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      empty  avgt    5    ≈ 10⁻⁶              B/op
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      small  avgt    5    48,000 ±   0,001    B/op
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      large  avgt    5    96,000 ±   0,001    B/op
OptionalBenchmark.optionalsWithMethodRefs:·gc.alloc.rate.norm       full  avgt    5    ≈ 10⁻⁵              B/op
```

If you replace `new Country("France")` with `new Country(null)`, the opimization will also break, and "full" scenario will become expectedly slower than "small" and "large".

Alternatively, the following dummy loop added to `setUp` will also prevent from overoptimizing `ofNullable` making the benchmark results more realistic.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Optional.ofNullable(null);
    }
```

#### 2.

Surprisingly, `nullChecks` benchmark also appears faster in "full" scenario. The reason here is class initialization barriers. Note that only "full" case initializes all related classes. In "small" and "large" cases `nullChecks` method refers to some classes that are not yet initialized. This prevents from compiling `nullChecks` efficiently.

If you explicitly initialize all the classes in `setUp`, e.g. by creating a dummy object, then "empty", "small" and "large" scenarios of `nullChecks` will become faster.

```
Room dummy = new Room(new Flat(new Floor(new Building(new Block(new District(new City(new Country("France"))))))))
```